# error while consuming wcf which is hosted in windows service for vs2008

Tags: wcf, windows-services, wcf-hosting

I have hosted wcf as in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733069.aspx.

In client application when I add service reference 'http://localhost:8000/ServiceModelSamples/service' , I am getting the following error:

```
There was an error downloading 'http://localhost:8000/ServiceModelSamples/service'.
Unable to connect to the remote server
No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:8000
Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'http://localhost:8000/ServiceModelSamples/service'.
Could not connect to http://localhost:8000/ServiceModelSamples/service. TCP error code 10061: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:8000. 
Unable to connect to the remote server
No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:8000
If the service is defined in the current solution, try building the solution and adding the service reference again.
```

I have reserved the url too like this C:\Windows\system32>netsh http add urlacl url=http://Service:8000/ServiceModelSamples/service/ user=mydomain\myuser.
  and also i am unable to see this 
http://localhost:8000/ServiceModelSamples/service/ from browser.

Comment: Hey friends this problem is solved as i started the service 'WCFWindowsServiceSample' from services(services.msc)

Answer (score 0):

Hey friends this problem is solved as i started the service 'WCFWindowsServiceSample' from services(services.msc)